# OpenMP support for Mac using clang or gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, clang, openmp

I am using Mac OS and I created a toy CMake project with OpenMP.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "omp.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;

#pragma omp parallel
    cout << "Hello OpenMP from thread " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(omp_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fopenmp")

add_executable(omp_test main.cpp)
```

When I tried `mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make -j` to build the project, I got `clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'`. It works well on Ubuntu. How can I change the CMakeList.txt to enable OpenMP support? Or If the problem can be solved using g++, how to do it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the openmp library? I don't use Mac, but I believe the command is `brew install libomp`

Comment: Unless you've installed `gcc` from Homebrew or from source, `g++` on macOS is really a symlink to Apples Clang++ compiler. It needs `-Xclang -fopenmp` to enable OpenMP support, but you also need to install the runtime.

Comment: @jignatius, @HristoIliev, thanks for your help. Actually I have installed both openmp and gcc from Homebrew. Now I know the way to solve the problem. I just used ```cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-9 ..``` to change the default compiler.

Comment: @Joxixi If you have found a way please shared as an answer with the community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem by changing the default compiler to g++. (Note: I have already installed gcc/g++ and the OpenMP library from Homebrew.)

I did not change `main.cpp` and `CMakeList.txt`, but when I built the project, I use

```
mkdir build && cd build && cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-9 .. && make -j
```

then the error `clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'` disappeared. Specifically, I added the option `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-9` to change the default compiler. Maybe the g++ version on your computer is not g++-9, then you can check it under the path `/user/local/bin/`.